# R (ggplot)- How to generate multiple plots (facets) based on data.frame with only one numeric variable and distinct categ. variables

Tags: r

starting with this kind of data:

> colnames(mydata)<-c("digit","freq","bool")
>
> ```
> 1.1 1 false
> 1.1 2 false
> 1.1 20 true
> 1.1 3 false
> 1.1 7 false
> 1.2 8 false
> 1.2 25 false
> 1.2 10 false
> 1.2 60 true
> 1.2 28 false
> 1.3 7 false
> 1.3 0 false
> 1.3 56 true
> 1.3 12 false
> 1.3 7 false
> 1.3 4 false
> 1.4 3 false
> 1.4 87 false
> 1.4 25 false
> 1.4 56 false
> 1.4 167 true
> 2.1 46 false
> 2.1 25 false
> 2.1 75 true
> 2.1 20 false
> 2.1 12 false
> 2.1 15 false
> ```

... I would like to create muliple plots based on the `digit` field in the data using ggplot2.

I tried

```
ggplot(mydata, aes(y = mydata$freq, x = seq(1, length(mydata$freq)))) + 
    geom_point() + 
    facet_wrap(~ mydata$digit)
```

But it won't work. Additionally, I would like to give two distinct colors to the `mydata$freq` data according to the `false or true $bool` annotation.

So, basically something like `geom_point(aes(colour=mydata$bool))` within each subplot (facet).

How can I make it work?

---

```
dput(mydata)
structure(list(digit = c(1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.2, 1.2, 1.2, 
1.2, 1.2, 1.3, 1.3, 1.3, 1.3, 1.3, 1.3, 1.4, 1.4, 1.4, 1.4, 1.4, 
2.1, 2.1, 2.1, 2.1, 2.1, 2.1), freq = c(1L, 2L, 20L, 3L, 7L, 
8L, 25L, 10L, 60L, 28L, 7L, 0L, 56L, 12L, 7L, 4L, 3L, 87L, 25L, 
56L, 167L, 46L, 25L, 75L, 20L, 12L, 15L), bool = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("false", 
"true"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("digit", "freq", "bool"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -27L))
```

Comment: Could you please share your data as the result of `dput(mydata)`? It will make it easier to correct the code after checking variable types.

Comment: First things first: don't ever use `$` inside `aes()`. The whole point of specifying `mydata` in `ggplot(mydata,...)` is that you then _do not_ refer to columns subsequently as `mydata$freq`, but just `freq`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to force dataframe columns where `ggplot2` just wants a column name. The correct syntax is more economical:

```
ggplot(mydata, aes(y = freq, x = 1:nrow(mydata), colour = bool)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  facet_wrap(~ digit) +
  labs(x = "1, 2, ..., n")
```

[image]

P.S. I can't vet for the way that you are stacking/visualizing the data, I have no idea what this comes from and what it represents.